# Power BI Table Tile Is Missing Rows. How do I Prevent This?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to run a report where I need to see a list of all of my invoices however I am encountering a problem where they are not all appearing in the Table I have created. These invoices all appear in my data view but when I put them into the report they appear to skips random ones. If you look at the index column on the left hand side of the screenshot at the bottom of the post you can see where the skips occur.  I do not believe I have any filters applied.

How do I prevent the table from skipping rows?

Thank you for your help.

[Missing Rows Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sozar.png)

Edit: It seems like there is some disconnect between my Customer Information Table and my Invoice Table. When I try to pull info from the Customer table and add that to the Invoice table for the report it skips rows.

Final Edit: I fixed it! It looks like the intermediate table that I connected it through filtered out some customers and invoices. I am still pretty new to Power BI and relational databases. I guess the lesson is.

The pathway between my tables was filtering my data without a "filter" being applied.

Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the tables was related was filtering my data without a "filter"

I figured it out so hey I'll pat myself on the back I guess.